# mongodb: query to check if item in an array contains a particular string

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a collection called `products` with the following items

```
[
  { 
    name: 'Product 1'
    images: ['http://staging.example.com/1', 'http://production.example.com/2'],
    ... 
  },
  { 
    name: 'Product 2'
    images: ['http://production.example.com/3'],
    ... 
  }
]
```

I want to find documents that contain string `staging` in the `images` array.

I tried couple of things like using $contains but mongo throws error saying I cannot use $contains with array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might need regex searching here.

Try:

```
db.collection.find({images: /staging/});
```

Comment: Ah! could have guessed that :) Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome~

Comment: Do you may be also know how to update `staging` to `production` using update? `db.collection.update({images: /staging/}, { $set: { 'images.$[]': ? } })`

Comment: `staging` is part of your string value. Update part of string is out of mongo's hand I think

Answer (score 0):

```
db.products.find({images: /staging/i});
```

I think this will may help